# Why does ambient occlusion make a black area above emission object?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, render-passes, ambient-occlusion

I did AO in compositor. The body of an emission object is invisible to the camera.
First screenshot - with TURNED ON AO
Second screenshot - with TURNED OFF AO

How it works and **how i can keep AO turned on, but fix this problem?**[image: 1 pic][image: 2 pic]

Blender 2.91

Comment: That dark spot is ambient occusion in action: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambient_occlusion. Did you tried to reduce the AO DIstance?

Comment: I did it, but it does not help. i tried basic 10m, 1m, 20 cm

Answer (score 1):

You're using the image as a factor, so that heavily white area is getting AO applied to it with massive influence.  Use a viewer node to look at the output of your AO node.